# How to draw strong lines between two cells in excel using python3?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a dataframe which I am plotting on excel. I want to thicken the boundary lines of all cells that lie in a given range.

Right now, my excel sheet looks like this:

[image: Current excel sheet]

Now, I want to draw the dark edges (0,21) and (0,24). Something like [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16W7di3yfWU78Lx0-pH5r7YUY_7oBPFb90wRN7RV09kQ/edit#gid=0).

Answer (score 0):

By strong lines, I assume you mean thick lines? Use openpyxl (https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html)

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Border, Side

wb = load_workbook(filename='yourFile.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

bd = Side(style='thick', color='000000')

for num in range (1, 25):
    ws['A{}'.format(num)].border=Border(right=bd)

wb.save('yourFile.xlsx')
```

Hope this helps.